# Date in the form: 20120405

Tags: r, date

Apologies for the simple question, but I can't find help for this type of date.

April 5th, 2012 is saved as numeric as "20120405"

How can I convert a vector of such values into usable dates?

Answer (score 5):

You just need the `as.Date` function:

```
R> x = "20120405"
R> as.Date(x, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2012-04-05"
```

Look at the help file: `?as.Date`, but essentially

- `%Y` means year in the form 2012, use `%y` for `12`.
- `%m` is the month.
- `%d` the day.

If your date had separators, say, 2012-04-05, then use something like: `%Y-%m-%d`. Alternatively, you can use:

```
R> strptime(x, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2012-04-05"
```

In particular, you can pass vectors of dates to these functions, so:

```
R> y = c("20120405", "20121212")
R> as.Date(y, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2012-04-05" "2012-12-12"
```

Answer (score 5):

like this,

```
(foo <- as.Date("20120405", "%Y%m%d"))
# "2012-04-05"
```

and maybe you want to `format` to get the month printed out

```
format(foo, "%Y %b %d")
# "2012 Apr 05"
```

You could take a look at [this page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

Answer (score 3):

With `strptime` you can convert it to `POSIXlt` class and with `as.Date` you can convert it to a `Date` class using format `"%Y%m%d"`:

```
strptime( "20120405",format="%Y%m%d")
[1] "2012-04-05"

as.Date( "20120405",format="%Y%m%d")
[1] "2012-04-05"
```

## Edit:

It is not really clear if you have character `"20120405"` or numeric `20120405`. In the latter case you have to convert to character first with `as.character(20120405)`

Comment: Thanks! It was the numeric that I think was causing the problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)  
ymd("20120405")
```